# Save text in a range of cells to .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save an active range of texts to a .txt file.

The range is a column F within the worksheet called "Reports". The number of rows depends on how many rows the report generates. This column F contains email addresses, which we need to upload to another system via a .txt file.

In the .txt file, each address will be located in a different line without other delimiters.

I have code, but it leaves the first line of the text file blank, starting with the second line.

```
Sub Macro_Newsletter()
Dim c As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim output As String

For Each r In Worksheets("Reports").Range("F2:F10000").Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        output = output & vbNewLine & c.Value
    Next c
Next r
Open "C:\Users\joseph.lin\Desktop\Database\Newsletter" For Output As #1
Print #1, output
Close
End Sub
```

I only know how to output them to outlook. Please help me figure out how to do this using VBA.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider.[Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Comment: Check the update @Introduction to VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```vb
Sub Macro_Newsletter()

    Dim wbText As Workbook
    Dim wsReports As Worksheet

    Set wbText = Workbooks.Add

    Set wsReports = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reports")

    With wsReports

        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row of emails

        .Range("F2:F" & lRow).Copy wbText.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

    End With

    'turn off alerts so you don't see messages about compatibility and such
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With wbText

        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\joseph.lin\Desktop\Database\Newsletter\Emails.txt", _
            FileFormat:=xlText
        .Close False

    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply record a macro (Developer Tab) and save it as a csv or .txt file - once you have this you can edit it as necessary. If you can save it to Outlook you should be able to save it to a text document.

This is a fairly common procedure and should be well documented within various resources.