# Saving Range from excel-sheet to text file

Tags: excel, vba

simple question but I'm stuck at this point.
I simply want to print/export a range (P21:P33) to a txt-file.

So far I tried this but it didnt work.

```
Sheets("EB_Ver").Range("P21:P33").SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\temp\" & "textfile" & Format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy hhmmss") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: There's no `Range.SaveAs` method. Perhaps copy those cells to a new workbook and then save.

Comment: https://chandoo.org/wp/save-range-as-text-using-vba/   or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998555/save-text-in-a-range-of-cells-to-txt-file